# Hosting Gradle artifacts on GitHub

Tags: android, maven, github, gradle

I know that people use GitHub to deploy Maven artifacts (in a new branch) but since we are using Gradle I would like to know if there is a simple way of handling those dependecies as well?

We have different little projects that are independent but used by our main project and we want to manage those dependencies without including them locally.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your question simply about the dependencies section of the build.gradle module file with `compile "com.example:example:1.0"` statements, or is it something different you are interested in?

Comment: Yes we have our own dependencies that are not published on any public repository. Instead we just have a GitHub repo for each of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an unofficial gradle plugin called [Gradle Git Repo plugin](https://github.com/layerhq/gradle-git-repo-plugin) that claims to do what you're looking for. Note however, that I did not play with it myself to verify that it works.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [JitPack](http://jitpack.io) to include your GitHub projects as dependencies. The idea is that JitPack provides a Maven repository where each package comes from a GitHub project.

It doesn't require that you upload files so it's quite easy to use. Instead when you request a file it builds it from source code.

There are two requirements to start using:
1. You need to have a build file in your project (Gradle or Maven)
2. You shoud create a GitHub release so that your project gets a version

Comment: Wow that looks awesome. However what do I need to do to get this working? When trying this with a simple Gradle project I just get Artifact "... Test-Lib.jar" not found. I do not have any release jar in my repo and JitPack does not seem to build it.

Comment: @K.D. Updated my answer. If you it doesn't seem to work just head to JitPack's [chat channel](https://gitter.im/jitpack/jitpack.io) or open a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/new)

Comment: This is great, and you don't need a tagged release - you can use a commit hash instead.